# Convert tkinter script which uses multiple image resources to .exe | image no such file or directory

Tags: python, tkinter, package, pyinstaller, software-distribution

I am trying to create an executable of my script, but running the .exe does not find the image. I have tried both onefile and multiples and pasting the images inside but it does not work.

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

root = Tk()
root.title("Tai Project")
root.geometry("600x600")
root.resizable(0, 0)

img = PhotoImage(file=resource_path("Tai_Project\ccc.png"))
img_opo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file=resource_path("Tai_Project\opo.png"))
img_label = tkinter.PhotoImage(file=resource_path("Tai_Project\labeltest.png"))
```

.spec

```
 a = Analysis(
    ['Tai_Interface.py'],
    pathex=['C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\Python1\\Tai_Project'],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[('ccc.png','.'),('opo.png','.'),('labeltest.png','.')],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='Tai_Interface',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
```

And the error message:

_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI88482\Tai_Project\ccc.png": no such file or directory

And my route is:
C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Python1\Tai_Project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> _tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI88482\Tai_Project\ccc.png": no
> such file or directory

This means that your spec file is written wrong and your files are not included in your temp dir.

**pathex** is path to your python.exe folder (not project)

**datas** must connect relative TEMP dir paths and absolute path to your files

For example:

I have file with absolute path:

```
C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\project\file.json
```

In code I refer to it like this:

```
resource_path("file.json")
```

Spec file must have:

```
datas = [("file.json","C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\project\\file.json", "DATA")]
```